# Need to use regex to get a string from a url

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have the following string

```
https://test.io/content/storage/id/urn:aaid:sc:US:8eda16d4-baba-4c90-84ca-0f4c215358a1;revision=0?component_id=e62a5567-066d-452a-b147-19d909396132
```

I need to use regex to get the following string

```
urn:aaid:sc:US:8eda16d4-baba-4c90-84ca-0f4c215358a1
```

from the `url` above.

The string will always begin with a urn and end with a letter or number.
Can someone please help? How can I do this using typescript?

Here's what I tried but it gave me an null value. Thanks!

```
    function extractAssetIdFromUrl(url: string) {
        // Regular expression to match the desired pattern
        const regex = /urn[\w-]+/;
        
        // Use the regex to find the match in the URL
        const match = url.match(regex);
    
        // Check if there is a match and return it, otherwise return null
        return match ? match[0] : null;
    }
```

Comment: what do you think `\w` matches? or more to the point, what doesn't it match that you want it to match?

Comment: I think it includes underscores. I want at least one letter or number upper case and lower case allowed not symbols @JaromandaX

Comment: and yet, you want it to match `:` and `-` ... you've added `-` but not `:`

Comment: o yea sorry it should match : that's allowed

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample inputs and expected outputs

Comment: You could match the format `\burn(?::[a-zA-Z]+)+:[a-z0-9]{8}(?:-[a-z0-9]{4}){3}-[a-z0-9]{12}\b` See https://regex101.com/r/Rcgc6z/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://regexr.com is very useful for understanding and deconstructing regex patterns.

This regex will do what you want based on the example pattern provided:

```
/urn:(?:[^:]+:)*[a-z0-9-]+/ig
```

To use this pattern to extract it from the example URL string you provided, you could do this:

```js
const url = 'https://test.io/content/storage/id/urn:aaid:sc:US:8eda16d4-baba-4c90-84ca-0f4c215358a1;revision=0?component_id=e62a5567-066d-452a-b147-19d909396132';
const urnId = /urn:(?:[^:]+:)*[a-z0-9-]+/ig.exec(url)[0];
// = 'urn:aaid:sc:US:8eda16d4-baba-4c90-84ca-0f4c215358a1'
```

As others have said, though, I would recommend first extracting the path out of the URL, as URLs can have things like query strings, which could also contain a pattern that matches this, resulting in possible unintended results.

Also, other have mentioned the fact that there appears to be a semicolon delimiter used in the URL, which could make your work much easier if that will reliably exist in the URL (and possibly even avoid the need for regex).

Comment: FYI there's no need to escape the `-` if it's the last character in your character class

Comment: @Phil TIL. Updated

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your id is terminated with a `;`, so I'd assume a regex for "starts with `urn:`", and "then everything that isn't `;`" should work just fine:

```js
const  url = ` https://test.io/content/storage/id/urn:aaid:sc:US:8eda16d4-baba-4c90-84ca-0f4c215358a1;revision=0?component_id=e62a5567-066d-452a-b147-19d909396132`;

const match = url.match(/\/(urn:[^;]+);/);
if (match) console.log(match[1]);
```

And then, of course,

Answer (score -1):

First extract the last path segment. Then you can match it against your required characters without having to worry about the query string or any other part of the URL

```js
function extractAssetIdFromUrl(url) {
  // as per requirements
  // "The string will always begin with a urn and end with a letter or number"
  const rx = /^urn[a-z0-9:-]*[a-z0-9]/i;
  
  const baseName = new URL(url).pathname.split('/').at(-1);
  return baseName.match(rx)?.[0] ?? null;
}

console.log(
  extractAssetIdFromUrl(
    "https://test.io/content/storage/id/urn:aaid:sc:US:8eda16d4-baba-4c90-84ca-0f4c215358a1;revision=0?component_id=e62a5567-066d-452a-b147-19d909396132",
  ),
);

console.log(
  extractAssetIdFromUrl(
    "https://example.com/foo/bar/baz",
  ),
);
```

Comment: Because I don't know how the url will look like. the only thing I know is that the asset id starts with urn and is followed by letters and numbers no symbols.

Comment: @RueVitale I've edited my answer to comply with the requirements you've set out